# Map not showing if using css "calc"

Tags: javascript, html, css, here-api

I have a here.com where I am using the geocoding example ([LINK](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics/geocoding.html)) exactly as described.

My `<div class="mapModal" id="mapContainer"></div>` has the following css:

```
.mapModal{
height:calc(100% - 50px);
width:calc(100% - 250px);
top:50px;
left:250px;
padding:5px;
position:absolute;
z-index:3;
```

}

Unfortunately this does not show the div with the map.

When I change the height to a fixed height like this: `height: 800px;` it works perfectly.

Is there any way to have a (screen fitted) dynamic size of the map container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parent element needs to have a defined height otherwise `height: 100%` will have no effect.

If you want the element to be `100%` of the window height / width you can use viewport units:

```
.mapModal{
   height:calc(100vh - 50px);
   width: calc(100vw - 250px);
   ...
}
```

Comment: @PrimuS You may also use: `html,body{height: 100%}`  and parent element height to 100% to make it work.

Comment: @Primus That would assume that there is no other elements between `body` and the parent. If map modal is nested deeper than this _all_ of the elements would need a defined height